# Batch how to convert text document to variable

Tags: batch-file

right now i'm working on a batch file that has a simple login and register feature. While I can register a user by creating a .txt file for their username and password, I cant figure out how to convert the contents of the .txt file into a variable that I can then test for to login the user. Here is what I have now. My problem is at :sign .

```css
@echo off
title Login
:a
cls
mode con: lines=10 cols=25
echo _________________________
echo     Select Your Choice
echo      1) Login
echo      2) Register
echo _________________________
set /p begi=:
if '%begi%'=='2' goto reg
if '%begi%'=='1' goto sign

:reg
cls
set u=
set /p u=Enter Your Username:
pause>nul
cls
set p=
set /p p=Enter your Password:
pause>nul
@echo %u% > user.txt
@echo %p% > pass.txt
pause>nul
goto a

:sign
cls
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REM write to the file:
echo Username>user.txt
REM read from the file (first line only):
set /p "un="<user.txt
echo %un%
```

by the way:
 your line `@echo %u% > user.txt` writes the variable plus a space to the file. This space will be part of the new variable (and will make trouble when using the new variable), if you read this file in. To avoid it, write `@echo %u%>user.txt`